# How to Merge unpartitioned space with partitioned system disk in Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, merge

I recently installed ubuntu-server and allocated 49GB for system
But there was unpartitioned 1tb storage. I forgot to setup that.

Here is the result of `lsblk`.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop1    7:1    0 61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
loop3    7:3    0 68.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21039
loop4    7:4    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12398
loop5    7:5    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop7    7:7    0 61.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/1026
loop8    7:8    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
loop9    7:9    0 68.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21260
sda      8:0    0   50G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 49.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0    1T  0 disk
sdc      8:32   0  250G  0 disk
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Now I need to merge `sda2` partition with `sdb`. `sda2` partition already has services and data. Like mysql , php etc..
I need to do that process without losing data.

Note that ubuntu-server does not have a GUI, I can only connect to it through ssh to a root user, hence it has to be done using commands.

Comment: sda, sdb and sdc are three different physical disks. You can't just merge them. If you can tell what  you want to use the space form then maybe we cab give a solution.

Comment: I need to use sdb space inside of sda1 drive. Inside of sda1 I have installed services. php , mysql all.